# SQL select field using a part of other field in another table

Tags: mysql, sql, join, inner-join

Hello I have the following two tables:

TableA:

```
Field1 | Field2
---------------
9911-4 | 4800
9911-6 | 400
9911-9 | 480
785-25 | 455
6523-1 | 221
```

And in the TableB I have:

```
ID   | Name
------------
9911 | A
785  | B
```

So, Field1 in TableA has the ID-number, and it must be jointed with Field ID of TableB.

Output must be:

```
  ID   | Name
  ------------
  9911 | A
  785  | B
```

but ID must be JOINT with Field1 of TableA. Field1 in TableA have NUMBER-NUMBER, where first number is the ID of TableB

Thanks in advance

Comment: From the output of tableB i dont see Id matching with Field1 in tableA. have you pasted wrong output. Can you paste desired output?

Comment: This is my desired output

Comment: this **should** be the answer, but if you concatenated the ID and some number to get Field1, then you have a structural problem.  And whoever thought that it was a good idea to do that should be punched violently in the face.  `SELECT TableB.ID, TableB.Name FROM TableB INNER JOIN TableA on TableB.ID = TableA.Field1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could try this:

```
select *
from TableA join TableB on id=substring(Field1,1,instr(Field1,'-')-1)
```

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT * from TableA join TableB on id=SUBSTRING_INDEX(field1,'-',2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically you find where the - is in the table and get a string between the beginning and that dash, then join to the column in the second table.

```
SELECT TABLEB.Name from TABLEA
INNER JOIN TABLEB ON 
SUBSTRING(TABLEA.Field1,0,CHARINDEX('-', TableA.Field1)) = TABLEB.ID
```

Comment: MySQL doesn't have a built-in CHARINDEX() function.  SQL-Server does, but question is tagged for MySQL.